# PHP: Function to classify html hex colours into a couple of simple string values

Tags: php, jquery, colors, hex, image

Is it possible to classify html hex colours into simple string values??

For example, the colour #CC3333, it's not completely red, but as a human we can assume that it's red. The colour #CCCCCC can be classified as white, because I don't want black or grey involved.

Possible simple values at least consist of:

- red
- white
- green

More classification is better, but I want at least these colours.

Can it be done?

Optional info:

> I'm creating a web apps that capture the pictures through webcam. The user can hold a white or red paper to the webcam and the apps detect the image's major colour. Then the user will be redirected to a different options depending on their colour. I've done the colour detection, but I just want classify it into several colour only, red,white,and green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat subjective question, because yes it can be done, but exactly how you would do it would depend on your specific application - colour itself is very subjective in the way that it is observed by the individual.

You would need to start by splitting the string into it's red, green and blue components:

```
$colourId = 'CC3333';
list($red, $green, $blue) = str_split($colourId, 2);
```

Then, it would probably be an idea to convert them to integers:

```
$red = hexdec($red);
$green = hexdec($green);
$blue = hexdec($blue);
```

Then you need to apply some sort of logic to it to determine which one of your classes it falls into. How you do this is really up to you, but maybe you could do something like this:

```
if (max($red, $green, $blue) - min($red, $green, $blue) < 10) {
  // If the values are all within a range of 10, we'll call it white
  $class = 'white'; 
} else if (max($red, $green, $blue) == $red) {
  // If red is the strongest, call it red
  $class = 'red'; 
} else if (max($red, $green, $blue) == $green) {
  // If green is the strongest, call it green
  $class = 'green'; 
} else if (max($red, $green, $blue) == $blue) {
  // If blue is the strongest, call it blue
  $class = 'blue'; 
}
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero.. It works like a charm.. Thanks.. May I ask, what if other colours involved, for example I want the colour 'brown'??

Comment: @IrmanAhmad See now that is where it starts to get interesting - browns tend to have a large amount of red and green, and not much blue  - but the same could be said of yellow. You would need to decide where your boundary between brown and yellow lies. Essentially it's just a huge if/else structure where you examine the amounts of each. For example, `if ($red > 150 && $green > 150 && $blue < 20) $class = 'yellow'; else if ($red > 60 && $green > 60 && $blue < 20) $class = 'brown';`

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to classified the color in RGB model it's better convert the color to HSL or HSV model , and then you can classified the color. for more information you can look [at:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_model)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to convert the hex format to rgb values. A simple Google search turned up [this page](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_convert_rgb_from_to_html_hex_color.xml). I haven't tested it, but if it doesn't work correctly then I'm sure you can find a different one that does.

Once you have the rgb values, you need to define your color ranges. The following code creates color ranges at every interval of 63.75 (that's 4 ranges per color, so 4*4*4 = 64 total ranges):

```
function findColorRange($colorArray){

    //assume $colorArray has the format [r,g,b], where r, g, and b are numbers in the range 0 - 255

    for($i = 0; $i < 256; $i += 51){ //find red range first
        if($colorArray[0] <= $i + 51/2 && $colorArray[0] >= $i - 51/2){
            for($n = 51; $n < 256; $n += 51){ //green
                if($colorArray[1] <= $n + 51/2 && $colorArray[1] >= $n - 51/2){
                    for($z = 51; $z < 256; $z += 51){ //blue
                        if($colorArray[2] <= $z + 51/2 && $colorArray[2] >= $z - 51/2){
                            return array($i,$n,$z);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above function would return an array that defines the color range of the color in question. From there, you could map the possible ranges to whatever strings you want. This would probably be most easily achieved by creating an associative array where the keys are the r,g,b values, and the values are the string. For example:

```
$colorMap = array(
    '0,0,0' => 'white',
    '51,0,0' => 'light gray'
)
```